# Amazon ec2 Bootstrap Actions

Tags: shell, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, sh

I want to update the instance, so I have a shell script that runs "sudo yum update", but then it asks for a user input of y/d/N. The bootstrapping gets stuck on this, currently my .sh file only has sudo yum install, how do I add in the input to type "y" when the command line prompts the user for an input.

Answer (score 2):

Add the `-y` flag afterwards:

```
sudo yum update -y
```